# Receive MQTT from multiple servers using Mosquitto brokier

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe, mosquitto

I have three VMs (VirtualBox, Ubuntu 18.04). All of them with Mosquitto broker (configured as default localhost:1883). Two VMs are PUB with private IPs and a "server" is a SUB (assigned via DHCP -bridged-). What I have is:

```
VM1 (PUB) [192.168.1.66]
VM (SUB) [192.168.1.55]   
VM2 (PUB) [192.168.1.74]
```

The idea is the SUB to receive MQTT from all PUBs, however, it only works if the MQTT client is configured as following

```
VM1 [192.168.1.66:1883] --> VM [192.168.1.66:1883]  <--  VM2 [192.168.1.74:1883]
```

So, the SUB will only receive messages from VM1 but not from VM2 neither other VMs (PUB). How can I configure the mosquitto and the client at the SUB to receive messages from all PUBs?

Comment: Why are you running multiple brokers?

Comment: MQTT Brokers are neither SUB nor PUB....they just receive MQTT messages from Publishers, and send out those messages to clients that have Subscribed to the Topic.  So what are you actually trying to achieve?  What does the end result look like??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MQTT client instance can only connect to a single MQTT Broker.

You have 2 options.

1. Run just one broker on any of the 3 machines and have all the publishing clients just publish to that broker and likewise the subscriber .
2. You can configure one of the brokers to bridge to all the other brokers and subscribe to any messages published on those broker so they they will appear in the topic hierarchy of that single broker.

   Details of how to configure mosquitto bridges can be found in the man page [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm45473494353120)

Comment: My issue with the first option is that the client MQTT doesn't send properly the messages. So, I'll go for the second option, however, in this case, the sender IP should be added to the mosquitto.conf, is there a way to append IPs automatically. I mean, I add VM1 IP manually but the VM2 wants to publish their messages and be bridged, how the bridge broker knows the IP of the new publisher and can add it automatically?

Comment: No, There is NO information about the publisher included in the message (unless the publisher adds it), this is just not how MQTT works

Comment: Your first comment doesn't make sense, from the publishing client's point of view there is no difference between publishing to localhost and publishing to a remote broker.

Comment: The link you've provided about Configuring bridge, says the following: address `address[:port] [address[:port]],
addresses address[:port] [address[:port]]`
`Specify the address and optionally the port of the bridge to connect to. This must be given for each bridge connection`. I know that MQTT doesn't work by IPs but topics, however, the mosquitto.conf requires the IP addresses of the bridges to connect to.

Comment: Yes, messages are published/subscribed to based on topics, but that is after you have connected to a broker and you need to know the IP address of the broker you want to connect to.

Comment: It works when configuring a single broker to bridge, however, I don't receive messages from a second broker. This is the part of bridge at the mosquitto.conf `connection manager
addresses 192.168.1.66:1883 192.168.1.74:1883
topic # out 0 
topic # in 0`

Comment: Re-read the doc, `addresses` is for fail over, you need to specify a totally separate bridge for each broker.